# JavaScript design pattern

Tags: javascript

can someone please explain to me the following JavaScript design pattern example and what it's trying to accomplish?

```
    var Knockback = { };
    Knockback.Observables = (function () {

        function Observables(model, mappings_info, view_model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.mappings_info = mappings_info;
            this.view_model = view_model;


            //logic in here
        }
        Observables.prototype.destroy = function () {
            //logic in here


            this.view_model = null;
            this.mappings_info = null;
            return this.model = null;
        };

        return Observables;
    })();

Knockback.observables = function(model, mappings_info, view_model, options) {
    return new Knockback.Observables(model, mappings_info, view_model, options);
};
```

Comment: You might like: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/ although am not able to say what you see here is covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Knockback` is a namespace. Values are stored inside `Knockback` so they do not clash with any global variables.

`Observables` is a constructor sitting inside `Knockback`. All of the logic is inside a closure (`(function () {})()`) for modularity

`observales` is used as a method of returning an instance of `Observables`, This is a way that people can use whats known as "scope safe constructors". In javascript if you call a constructor without new, then the this object defaults to the `window`, polluting your global namespace again.

I'm not sure how much you know about javascript, but I hope this helps.

-------------------------------- updated --------------

1) The closure functions the same as without a closure, that is correct (At the time of my answer i didnt know that there were no "private" variables). But this pattern also allows you to place this constructor wherever you please. Imagine if the namespace (Knockback) name changed to KB. You could place the constructor there without even needed to change a line of code inside the closure.

2) The Knockback.observer function may be a bloat (which i personally dont think it is) but the "scope safe" factor is considered a best practise. consider:

```
var standardCorrectInvokation = new Knockback.Observer('model', 'mappings_info', 'view_model');

var aboutToLooseMyJobInvokation = Knockback.Observer('this', 'is', 'un-intuative');
//goodbye global namespace
alert(window.model); // this
alert(window.mappings_info); // is
alert(window.view_model); // un-intuative
//goodbye job at reputable web firm
```

Id like to point out that the boys as ES5 camp fixed this problem, but strict mode is not implemented in all browsers yet (IE.. ahem ahem)

Comment: actually I don't see much sense in that self-invoking anonymous function/closure. There is nothing which it closes over. Also, the "constructor" call looks far too bloated and unnecesarry.